# Distance between objects on an image

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to find the shortest distance between the white spots shown in the image.It would be really helpful if somebody could point me in the general direction of what to do.

**Note Using Python 3**

[image: image_link]

Comment: Kindly show what have you tried so far so that we can suggest and help?.

Comment: Also, please let us know if this is a one-time measurement you need to make or you'd like to automate the measurement of distance between two white points?

Comment: @SauravRai ,The thing is, I am new to image processing and only have a basic Idea on images. Here my approach is to identify the white spots as objects and hence obtain their relative distances.Yet, I dont even know the names of what algorithms to employ or what datasets(I belive I might have to make them) to use.So I would be really greatful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @achow ,I want to track the joint positions with a certain time gap.So the algorithm must give me the measurements at regular intervals of time.The input of the algorithm will be the image of the gesture at the end of the time period.